# Reduce list of lists if entries match

Tags: python, list, set

I have a list in python which looks like

```
[['boy','121','is a male child'],['boy','121','is male'],['boy','121','is a child'],['girl','122','is a female child'],['girl','122','is a child']]
```

I want to reduce the list based on the first 2 entries in each list, to get

```
[['boy','121',is a male child, is male, is a child'],['girl','122','is a female child','is a child']]
```

is there a way to do this efficiently without creating a dummy list?

Comment: I don't think a list of lists is the best structure for this. Why not something like `{('boy', 121): ['is a male child', 'is male', 'is a child'], ...}`?

Comment: that's also fine, it's just that I get the first format from an index search, and want to reduce it based on if the 1st 2 entries match-- if that makes sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Have you *tried* anything? What happened?

Comment: I guess the `is a male child` in the output must be in quotes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a more pythonic way for such task you can use a dictionary :

```
>>> li=[['boy','121','is a male child'],['boy','121','is male'],['boy','121','is a child'],['girl','122','is a female child'],['girl','122','is a child']]
>>> 
>>> d={}
>>> 
>>> for i,j,k in li:
...   d.setdefault((i,j),[]).append(k)
... 
>>> d
{('boy', '121'): ['is a male child', 'is male', 'is a child'], ('girl', '122'): ['is a female child', 'is a child']}
```

> [**setdefault(key[, default])**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)
>
> If key is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert key with a value of default and return default. default defaults to None.

And if you want to have the elements within 1 container you can loop over the items and convert the value to `tuple` then ad it with key:

```
>>> [i+tuple(j) for i,j in d.items()]
[('boy', '121', 'is a male child', 'is male', 'is a child'), ('girl', '122', 'is a female child', 'is a child')]
```

As @jonrsharpe says as a more elegant way you can also use `collections.defaultdict` :

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> 
>>> d=defaultdict(list)
>>> for i,j,k in li:
...   d[i,j].append(k)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {('boy', '121'): ['is a male child', 'is male', 'is a child'], ('girl', '122'): ['is a female child', 'is a child']})
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe *simplify*? why use another import when it could be done with a built-in method?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes its True but in this case and most of tasks that can be solves with both `setdefault` and `defaultdict` the `setdefault` has  more performance!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah! <sub>for this task ;)</sub>

Comment: If you're answering a different question, with a different task where performance is critical and the difference is significant, then by all means dismiss readability and recommend `setdefault` alone. You seem unwilling to even consider `defaultdict`, though, so I don't see any point to discussing this further.

Comment: @jonrsharpe No actually i like `defaultdict` my self because it is more flexible and also `setdefault` do just a part of its task! and im agree that the performance difference is not much! any way i'll edit the answer with `defaultdict`, thanks for attention ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for this :

```
>>> l = [['boy','121','is a male child'],['boy','121','is male'],['boy','121','is a child'],['girl','122','is a female child'],['girl','122','is a child']]
>>> import itertools
>>> [k+[m[2] for m in v] for k,v in itertools.groupby(l,key = lambda x:x[:2])]
[['boy', '121', 'is a male child', 'is male', 'is a child'], ['girl', '122', 'is a female child', 'is a child']]
```

From the documentation

> ```
> itertools.groupby(iterable[, key])
> ```
>
> Make an iterator that returns consecutive keys and groups from the iterable. The key is a function computing a key value for each
>   element.